# How does $LL(n)$ languages compare with $LR(0)$, for $n>0$?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, parsers

In the context of languages (not grammars), I know following:

> 1. $LL(0) \subset LL(1) \subset LL(2) \subset \cdots \subset LL(k)$
> 2. $LR(0) \subset SLR(1) = LALR(1) = LR(1) = SLR(k) = LALR(k) = LR(k)$
> 3. $LL(0)\subset LR(0)$
> 4. $LL(n)\subset LR(1)$ for all $n$'s

How does $LL(n)$ languages compare with $LR(0)$, for $n>1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are incomparable.

1. Every $LR(0)$ language has the prefix property (no sentence is a prefix of another sentence). But many $LL(k)$ languages don't have this property ($a^*$, for example).
2. The language $\{a^nb^mc\mid n\ge m\ge 0\}$ is $LR(0)$ but is not $LL(k)$ for any $k$.

Comment: Any $LL(k)$ language which is not $LR(0)$?

Comment: @anir: see point 1: $a^*$ is not $LR(0)$ (because it does not have the prefix property).