# Equivalence of LR(k) and LL(k′) parsers

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, parsers, lr-k

Are there languages that can be parsed by an LR(k) parser but not by an LL(k′) parser for any k′?

Comment: Related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/43

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $\{a^i b^j c \mid i \ge j \ge 0\}$ can be parsed by a $LR(0)$ parser but not by any $LL(k')$ parser for any $k'$.  See [How does $LL(n)$ languages compare with $LR(0)$, for $n>0$?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/118458/755).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/36652221/781723 and [Language theoretic comparison of LL and LR grammars](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/43/755).